# Update Else Insert without Update Strategy

Tags: informatica, upsert

I'm inserting from a source table to the target table. If the source record already exists in the target, then it will update else insert. I have done this without using Update strategy. In session properties, I have set as treat rows as 'Update' and in the mapping target properties, I selected 'Insert' and 'Update Else Insert' checkbox. Also, I have chosen a primary key in the target table as well. But while running the session every time, it is always inserting the same rows again and again. I.e. duplicate rows are inserting instead of update the record. am I doing anything wrong?

Comment: Try using only "Update else Insert". I assume there is a key set on DB?

Comment: If there is a primary key in the target, data will not be inserted

Answer (score 0):

The database table should have primary keys defined for this to work.